# Highlights the values below Average in CrystalReport 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

Below is the image of my crystal reports in VS2008. I want to highlight the values (Red color) which are the below average of the total values. Like 'AAG' has total value 1551 and the average of 10 days is 1551/10 = 155.1. Now which date has value below than 155 should highlights in Red color(150,143,148,129,142). How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the following

1) Go to format object -> border tab -> background formula field

paste this formula

```
IF GridRowColumnValue ("Table.Total")  < 1550
then color(150,143,148,129,142)    
else crWhite
```

Comment: I want for dynamic values. For every Name and result of total will be different for different date.